# css - 100% cover position absolute with responsive top

Tags: css

I'm using leaflet js

I need the map to be 100% width and height

I know I can do with with height: 100%; if the html, body is 100%.

That doesn't work in my current set up so I'm using absolute positioning to make it 100% height and width.

I need a header at the top.

I can use the top on the absolute positioning to move the map down but I don't like this because the height of the header could change.

Is it possible to show the header and still absolute position the map

```js
let mymap = L.map('map').setView([54.5, -2], 6);

   L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHRtdCIsImEiOiJjajhqeWhjOW8wN2JvMndwbTlqaTV0YjhhIn0.rlysm052tK3vDdZSSg-wQg'
   }).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

header{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#map {
    //height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
</header>
   
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: try calc()? ex: `height: calc(100% - 10px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Just add

```
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
```

to your header styles.

```js
let mymap = L.map('map').setView([54.5, -2], 6);

   L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHRtdCIsImEiOiJjajhqeWhjOW8wN2JvMndwbTlqaTV0YjhhIn0.rlysm052tK3vDdZSSg-wQg'
   }).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

header{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
</header>
   
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let mymap = L.map('map').setView([54.5, -2], 6);

   L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHRtdCIsImEiOiJjajhqeWhjOW8wN2JvMndwbTlqaTV0YjhhIn0.rlysm052tK3vDdZSSg-wQg'
   }).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

header{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#map {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
</header>
   
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: He said the height of the header is dynamic so calc isn't really an option